# How to configure PhpMyAdmin to prevent users from modifying other user settings in the `phpmyadmin` table?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to allow multiple configurations of PhpMyAdmin depending on users, but I cannot figure out how to protect users from having their configuration changed by others.

I need to give them the rights to the phpmyadmin db, but that would be too much.
All the solutions I could think of are problematic:

**Solution 1**:
Force a UI where the phpmyadmin db is hidden, and where access to the "Settings" tab is forbidden by the "User group" definition.

Problem: Since the SQL Query Console cannot be hidden, then a user can still connect to phpmyadmin db and make changes using command line.

**Solution 2**:
Let the user create all the tables of pma in a dedicated db with his own name.

Problem: PhpMyAdmin does not seem to access this, since the config.inc.php states that all the pma tables should be in a db called "phpmyadmin".

What to do to be perfectly safe?

Thanks.

Comment: phpMyAdmin does not handle users, users are handled by the MySQL server.  PMA is just a GUI for accessing a MySQL server.   How are you creating these users?

Comment: The users are created within MySQL using the phpmyadmin UI. When they connect to their UI, changes in the settings are stored in the phpmyadmin db, with their username as reference. In order to do that, they should have appropriate privileges to this db. Which is incompatible with preventing them from corrupting settings of other users. You see what I mean?

Comment: "Problem: Since the SQL Query Console cannot be hidden, then a user can still connect to phpmyadmin db and make changes using command line." "Solution" delete or comment out the SQL tab in the PHP/HTML source code and add a `exit()` on the top in the file where the link pointed to..

Comment: I see.  I haven't used PMA in years so it must have changed, I don't even remember having a separate database for PHPMyAdmin.  Seems like a bad design if it requires the logged in user to have access to that database instead of using a dedicated user to perform settings updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to give them the rights to the phpmyadmin db

Why? This isn't a requirement of phpMyAdmin when you're using a [controluser account](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_controluser), so as far as phpMyAdmin is concerned there is no need for your individual users to have access to the 'phpmyadmin' database.

Within phpMyAdmin, the user accounts and configuration are tracked separately, so as long as you configure the user accounts to not have permission for the phpmyadmin database, any user can change their own preferences but not affect other users.

See also the documentation at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage

I suggest that, in keeping with standard security best practices, for each user you grant only the permissions they need — which will not include access on the phpmyadmin database. Using the controluser account will allow phpMyAdmin to manage the user preferences without granting the users access to modify or change other user's preferences.

That should accomplish what you've asked for here.

Comment: Ok, in fact, my phpMyAdmin was badly configured in a bad attempt to improve security. I had removed the possibility to connect without password, and many months later I had forgotten why I need the two lines that define the control user within **config.inc.php**. I put back the identification line for the control user, and now everything works fine. I wasted so many hours on this :(

Comment: Glad you're making progress, though! Let us know if you have any other troubles.